# How to fix a click which is not working specific to a website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The HTML code  for the login is as follows:

```
<input id="login:login_btn" name="login:login_btn" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('login',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){},'similarityGroupingId':'login:login_btn','parameters':{'login:login_btn':'login:login_btn'} } );return false;" value="Login" style="width:100%;margin-left:7px;" type="button">
```

I am trying to do a simple click on login button. My code is here:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\SmitaThakur\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://myportal-qa.pricechopper.com/mobile/eas/login.seam");
driver.findElement(By.id("login:username")).sendKeys("757823");
driver.findElement(By.id("login:password")).sendKeys("texas5");
driver.findElement(By.id("login:login_btn")).click();
```

I have tried other clicks too.
This code does a click but nothing happens. Neither next page appears nor any error appears. I have tried same code with other websites and those works fine. The same code for same website is working fine on same laptop but with login as different person.

Comment: This could be an error of the site you are automating...

Comment: Hi @smita, try giving some delay before clicking like `Thread.sleep(3)`

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the click line and run the test in debug. Make sure the page is completely loaded, now start up the script again. Does it work now? If it does, it's likely a timing issue. Try to find the last thing to load on the page and wait for it then attempt the click.

Answer (score 0):

The element is a [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) element so identify the element you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id$='login_btn'][name$='login_btn'][value='Login']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'login_btn') and contains(@name, 'login_btn')][@value='Login']"))).click();
  ```